# I am having an error while opening my heroku app, it says code=H12 and also status 503

Tags: node.js, heroku

Error particularly occurs when trying to browse something to be extracted from db.

e.g.
if I go to my landing page, nice and simple no db connected there, it opens.

but when trying to go to `/books` then it will throw an error and no problem `/register` or `/login`but after logging in or register the same error occurs.

logs when I go to `landing page` or `/login`

```
at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/landing.css" host=zen-like-name.herokuapp.com request_id='some hex numbers' fwd="ip" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https

at=info method=GET path="/stylesheets/main.css" host=zen-like-name.herokuapp.com request_id='some hex numbers' fwd="ip" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=237 protocol=https
```

logs when trying to logon or browse /books page

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/login" host=zen-like-name.herokuapp.com request_id="some hex numbers" fwd="IP" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/books" host=zen-like-name.herokuapp.com request_id="some hex numbers" fwd="IP" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

1. noje.js
2. mongolab connected to the app
3. install mongoose on heroko `'heroku run npm install mongoose'`

Comment: H12 is request timeout, it looks like when you access mongoose (login and browse) something takes too long or it cannot connect to the DB. Any other error at application startup?

Comment: I think I have found the solution. I had to allow all of the IP address.